# npm restful api suddenly no longer working

Tags: api, express, npm, pg-promise

I followed this tutorial to create a restful api with npm and postgres

[Designing a RESTful API With Node and Postgres](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.V6qjM5N97Vo)

I got everything to work without a problem, closed the server and went to other things.. when I got back, the routing stopped working suddenly giving `404 error`.. I checked everything related to routing and I can't find the problem!

When I connect to `localhost:3000` I get the correct express homepage
but when I try to access the api, `localhost:3000/api/patients` the `404 error` page appears

Here is my code

`index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../queries');


router.get('/api/patients', db.getAllPatients);


module.exports = router;
```

`queries.js`

```
var promise = require('bluebird');

var options = {
  // Initialization Options
  promiseLib: promise
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var connectionString = 'postgres://localhost:5432/maindb'
var db = pgp(connectionString);

module.exports = {
  getAllPatients: getAllPatients
}

function getAllPatients(req, res, next) {
  db.any('select * from patients where deleted = false')
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200)
        .json({
          status: 'success',
          data: data,
          message: 'Retrieved ALL patients'
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return next(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is definitely something to do with your use of `express.js`, but not related to the use of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something was wrong with `express` installation, something corrupted it.

I recreated the project from point zero and specified which version of `express` and `bluebird` to install, and everything seems to work fine without any problems.